# Can I set the max or min zoom on a CartoDB embed?

Tags: carto, zoom

I'm using the default iframe embed to display two CartoDB maps, but I'd like to prevent people from zooming out past a certain point, or if that isn't possible, to prevent zooming at all.

Can I do that? I sniffed around but I don't see anything obvious. I tried adding  `&maxzoom=5` to the URL, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in the embed visualization. But you can do it using CartoDB.js, example here:

http://bl.ocks.org/xavijam/10777294

Sorry for the late response, but I hope it helps in the future :).